# The number of solutions in a linear congruence.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Why is the number of solutions in a linear congruence $ax\equiv b(mod m)$ equal to the $gcd(a,m)$ such that $gcd(a,m)$ divides $b$?

Comment: It's not.  Try $2x\equiv 1\pmod 4$.

Comment: what about if gcd(a,m) divides b? just edited my question

Comment: The [Mathworld article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearCongruenceEquation.html) describes the solutions.

Comment: Also [The Art of Problem Solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Linear_congruence) discussion is good.

Comment: alright i'll check them out.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\ d = \gcd(A,M)\,$ and $\, a,b,m = [A,B,M]/d =  A/d,\,B/d,\,M/d.\ $ Then

$$\begin{align} A x \equiv&\ B\pmod{\!M}\\
 \iff\ Ax\ -&\ B\ =\ j M,\quad\, {\rm for\ some}\ \ j\in\Bbb Z\\
  \iff\ ax\,\ -&\ b\,\ =\,\ j\, m,\quad {\rm for\ some}\ \ j\in\Bbb Z,\, \text{ by scaling by $d$ or $d^{-1}$} \\
\iff\,\ ax\equiv&\ b\,\ \pmod{\!m}\\
\iff\,\ \ \  x\equiv&\: b/a\!\!\!\!\pmod{\!m}\quad\text{[note $a^{-1}$ exists by $\,\gcd(a,m)=1$]}
\end{align}$$

The root $\,x\equiv b/a\pmod{\!m}\,$ lifts to $\,\color{#c00}d\,$ roots $\bmod \color{#c00}{d}m = M\,$ since

$$\begin{align}
\bmod{dm}\!:\ \ b/a + jm\equiv&\ b/a + km\\
\iff\qquad\ \ (j-k)m\equiv&\ 0\\
\iff\  md\mid (j-k)m\quad &\\
\iff\  d\ \,\mid\,\  j-k\qquad\ \ \ &\\
\iff\ \ j\equiv k\pmod{\!d}
\end{align}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$$

Thus choosing normal reps $\,j=0,1,2,\ldots\,d\!-\!1\,$ yields precisely $\color{#c00}d$ roots $\bmod M,\,$ namely

$$ \{ b/a + j\, m\ : \ j = 0,1,2,\ldots,d\!-\!1\}\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad $$

Comment: what is the rule that states what you did from $ax\equiv b(\mod m)$ to $x\equiv b/a (\mod m)$? I've seen it before but I forgot. thanks

Comment: @The We multiplied both sides of the congruence by $\,a^{-1},\,$ which is valid by the [Congruence Product Rule.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) It helps to think of congruences as generalized equalities, since they enjoy many of the same properties of equations (e.g. the linked Congruence Laws). Using a symbol visually similar to an equal sign helps to emphasize that analogy.

Comment: alright I shall study those first, thanks! can you teach me how to think about this more "fluidly"? I don't feel a strong grasp of this modular arithmetic although I do understand intuitively why $ax\equiv b(\mod m)$ means ax-my=b. I still don't feel comfortable with it.